# Rejected for having duplicate accounts on company's career site

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, applications, websites

After i finished my Bachelor degree I was looking for a job in some international companies so I was creating accounts on their career sites and applying directly from their systems. Then I decided to continue my master degree and I didn't apply more.

Recently I was applying again as I finished my Master degree but I had to create new accounts as I am not using my old email address anymore.

So one company contacted me for a job interview over the phone and We had a call immediately as I was free and ready for these calls. Everything went well and we deal they will contact me by email and send me the dates when I can come to their office.

I was glad then the next day I received an email from HR that they were searching my name and they found duplicated accounts with the same name and they rejected my application based on this behavior.

I tried to explain them that I have created the old one 2 years ago when I was looking for a job and I stopped using my old email address so I have created new profile with my current email address but it didn't change anything with them.

I am very worried now if it will be the same with my other applications in the other companies and I will be rejected again for this reason which I didn't have in mind at all.

How can I avoid something like this happening again?  What can I do to be proactive with letting the company know if I have created a profile years earlier?

Comment: Consider yourself fortunate that you don't have to work for a company that foolish.

Comment: Did you actually speak to someone?  How about the person who you interviewed with (if they weren't HR)? Say "fair enough..... so how do I update the email on an account I haven't used in two years and can't reset the password because that email is no longer valid?"  Seems awfully rigid.

Comment: It sounds like you need to call and talk to someone directly. Explain the situation and ask them to look at the activity on the two accounts. It may be very clear for them to see that one was accessed 2 years ago and not recently. I assume they are hostile toward people who apply with several accounts to increase their chances of an interview - which you clearly did not do.

Comment: I can see a company reject you for duplicate applications from multiple sources (I.E. two agencies) but this is the first time I've ever heard about anything like this.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - if they haven't used it in two years, and "forgot password," the process for logging in (pre-requisite for changing the email) would include a link to reset the password ***being sent to the email on file,*** which, by the description, seems like it is no longer a valid one.  So how would they do that?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Many system are hosted services (company won't be able to), and almost none will allow alterations to an account with personal information without proper credentials (or, at least, they shouldn't) for that account, which no one at the company should be able to access.  I certainly wouldn't trust that an HR generalist would be able to do that, and most companies don't have HR technical expertise, and HR systems are way down on the list in terms of allocating IT resources.  I'm IT now, was HRIS/HR technical support before that, so that's my own slanted perspective on it.

Comment: It seems completely bizarre and is probably not the whole story?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - that's changing the basic, identifying information that can be used to access the account, though.  Not all information that is kept is or should be the same. Depending on the industry or how robust the liability prevention is, I'd think being able to do that would raise red flags with compliance people.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Like I said, my experience was managing, administering, procuring, designing and programming exactly these kinds of systems, so the problems would be actual ones. I've also had experience with companies that are lax on stuff like that and allowed me to have their entire databases downloaded to my local computer with unencrypted customer passwords - and that company offered "credit protection and monitoring" services, so I could get ALL of any/all customers' private financial data, so I've also seen what happens when companies don't protect for stuff like that.

Comment: An HRIS (even the applicant tracking portion) could very well contain SS#s, dates of birth, etc, so, no, an admin probably shouldn't be able to access and edit a customer profile. Maybe you think I fall on the "too careful," side, but we see too many instances of companies that aren't careful enough in the news every day - companies that certainly have the resources to do better.  I'll get off the soapbox now.  It is very possible that there is no mechanism for just changing the email, though, is more my point.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet This is one good reason to autodelete accounts that haven't been accessed for more than "N" days. I am sure OP is not the first one with this problem and he won't be the last. A couple of years ago, when I was looking to change job, I created online accounts with several companies. Once I got the job with one of them, I stopped logging in to any of them. I don't even remember the sites where I created the account, leave alone the email or username I used there. So should that automatically disqualify me from applying there in future?

Answer (score 12):

I would consider this a very strange behavior for a hiring company.  I'm certain I must have multiple accounts on at least one company site, and I've only applied for jobs a handful of times.

The only reasonable concern on their side is that you are trying to cover up some misbehavior or avoid some bad thing that was tied to the first account, but given they *found* that first account and there is nothing negative there (I assume?), it sounds like they're just being unreasonable.

I don't think you need to worry about this with other companies.  Just carry on applying like you have been, and if your initial account is unrecoverable, make a new one.  You're hardly the first person to create one account with your undergrad email, then lose access to that, and have to create a new one with gmail/etc.